# MSCRM 2015: Rename legend in bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, bar-chart, dynamics-crm-2015

I have created a bar chart with two categories and one series as below.

Chart condition
[image]

Chart
[image]

The requirement is to change the Legend names Open and Disqualified to Ongoing and Cancelled. The Legend names are nothing but the 2nd Category (Status).
I went through the code, but not able to figure it out where to add the Legend names.Kindly suggest some solution if any.
Below is the code I have given for reference.

```
 <visualization>
  <visualizationid>{C9D241BD-29E6-E711-80DC-00505695684B}</visualizationid>
  <name>Assessment Revenue by Year</name>
  <primaryentitytypecode>lead</primaryentitytypecode>
  <datadescription>
    <datadefinition>
      <fetchcollection>
        <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
          <entity name="lead">
            <attribute name="new_assessmentyear" groupby="true" alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0" />
            <attribute name="pjdm_income" aggregate="sum" alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0" />
            <attribute name="statecode" groupby="true" alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_13" />
          </entity>
        </fetch>
      </fetchcollection>
      <categorycollection>
        <category alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0">
          <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0" />
          </measurecollection>
        </category>
      </categorycollection>
    </datadefinition>
  </datadescription>
  <presentationdescription>
    <Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="91,151,213; 237,125,49; 160,116,166; 255,192,0; 68,114,196; 112,173,71; 37,94,145; 158,72,14; 117,55,125; 153,115,0; 38,68,120; 67,104,43; 124,175,221; 241,151,90; 186,144,192; 255,205,51; 105,142,208; 140,193,104; 50,125,194; 210,96,18; 150,83,159; 204,154,0; 51,90,161; 90,138,57;">
      <Series>
        <Series ChartType="Column" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40" />
      </Series>
      <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea BorderColor="White" BorderDashStyle="Solid">
          <AxisY LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
            <MajorGrid LineColor="239, 242, 246" />
            <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
            <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
          </AxisY>
          <AxisX LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
            <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
            <MajorGrid LineColor="Transparent" />
            <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
          </AxisX>
        </ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
      <Titles>
        <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
      </Titles>
      <Legends>
        <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="right" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
      </Legends>
    </Chart>
  </presentationdescription>
  <isdefault>false</isdefault>
</visualization>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the chart display then Use the LegendText property inside each series you want to change:

```
   <Series ChartType="Column" LegendText="Ongoing"  DrawSideBySide= "False" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40">
   <Series ChartType="Column" LegendText="Cancelled" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40">
```

Otherwise the statecode optionset can be customized in Lead entity to reflect across the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But in this case, though two bars are appearing on the chart based on the category selection, only one series is there in the chart xml.                                                                     
      <Series>
        <Series ChartType="Column" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40" />
</Series> This is generated OOB in MSCRM based on the chart configuration.Is there any other way?

Comment: @Nithya If you insist to have your Legend dynamic then the only option i see is to change the display names of Case Status.